# Java list method declaration?

Tags: java, list, methods

I am having difficulty understanding this code. I'm unsure if the line that contains a comment is declaring a method or not. I tried googling for list methods but unfortunately didn't find anything. Thank you :)

```
    List<String> getBrands(String color) {//I don't understand this line of code
        List<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        if(color.equals("amber")) {
            brands.add("Jack Amber");
            brands.add("Red Moose");
        } else {
            brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");
            brands.add("Gout Stout");
        }
        return brands;
    }

}
```

Comment: Simple - `getBrands` is a method which is returning a `List<String>` (read - list of strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's declaring the method of return type `List<String>`, string being the generic type of the list.

Comment: return type `List<String>`

Comment: For some reason the mobile site won't let me put any greater or less then icons. But yea.

Comment: If the method isn't declared as public, is it by default set as protected?

Comment: @Moonear the default scope is package-protected, which means all the classes of the same package, and only these classes can access it whereas protected also allows subclasses to access these methods even if they are declared in other packages

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**When designing a method, you need to know the following parts**.

```
public static void myMethod(int parameter) throws someException {
   //method body
}
```

1. access modifier (public)
2. optional specifier (static)
3. return type (void)
4. method name (myMethod)
5. parameter list (int parameter)
6. optional exception (throws someException)
7. method body ({ // method body })

> > Note :: access modifier,optional specifier and optional exception are **optional**. Others are **required**.

In your code,

```
 List<String> getBrands(String color) {
    // method body
 }

 /*

 Your access modifier is default (no declaration)
 List<String> is return type
 getBrands is method name
 (String color) is parameter list
 { // .... } is method body

 */
```

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining it. Greatly appreciated :)